# Quickbooks .iif validator

Tags: quickbooks

Is there some way to validate .iif files before doing the import?  It seems Quickbooks is not very nice when an import fails.  Sometimes you don't get an error and it just skips the record.  I'm importing invoices.

Answer (score 1):

.IIF files have been a deprecated file format for over 10 years now.

They are known to corrupt QuickBooks company files. They should not be used as there are better alternatives -- look into the QuickBooks SDK.

What you're seeing may very well not be records being skipped, but instead be actual corruption of the company file.

Comment: Thanks, I would love to upgrade to quick books online or fresh books but you know how legacy goes.  I did find the issue with the .iif

Comment: There's no need to upgrade to Online or Freshbooks - The Windows desktop versions of QuickBooks have supported qbXML as an import/integration format for 10+ years now. Have fun corrupting your data with .IIF though...

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr.  - I saw Intuit shared an IIF import kit. I understand qbXML with SDK is preferred based on what you've posted, but as far as corruption goes - can you elaborate? If the data imports correctly have you seen corruption, is the corruption just to the data that's being imported or the entire data file, etc.

Comment: @SpaghettiWestern So I think I've heard this may have changed with more recent versions of QuickBooks, but... we saw both instances. Essentially IIF used to bypass all data validation, so you could do things like import invoices that referenced invalid or non-existent accounts, which would throw off not only the invoice balance itself, but the corresponding customer balance, and the entire chart of accounts balance because money was going to invalid places on the invoice. So you could still _use_ QuickBooks... just none of the reports actually added up correctly to what you'd expect them to.